# Слово «желудёвый» имеет корень желуд-/-желуд-

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Слово *желудёвый* имеет корень *желуд-/-желуд-*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно:

*Слово желудёвый имеет корень желуд-*.

Давайте разберëм его по морфемам: *желуд-ëв-ый*.

При корне используется один висячий дефис, поэтому ставим один: *желуд-*.